# Terminology: Tangential Component, Normal Component

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation

Suppose I have a vector field $F$ defined on $\Bbb R^3$, where the input is a path $c:t \rightarrow (x(t),y(t),z(t))$ , a.k.a $F(c(t))$. I am encountering the terms "tangent component", and "vector component" in my studies (without definition) and with a decent amount of Google searches, frankly I am still confused what they mean.

Is this the correct interpretation:

The tangent component of $F(c(t))$ is $F(c(t))\cdot \frac {c'(t)} {||c'(t)||}$,

and the normal compoment of $F(c(t))$ is $F(c(t))\cdot \frac {n(t)} {||n(t)||}$,
where $n(t)$ is the normal to $c'(t)$  ?

Edit: To clarify, here is the references in my textbook in relation to Stokes Theorem.

[image]

Comment: Please give detailed context here. Have you learned about the principal normal vector to a curve (Frenet frame)?

Comment: @TedShifrin I have attached a picture of the reference to the aforementioned terms as a picture. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion comes from two different contexts. For the line integral, you compute the tangential component of $\mathbf F$ — the part of the vector field tangent to the curve. For the surface integral, you compute the component of $\nabla\times\mathbf F$ normal to the *surface*.

Comment: But what is the tangential component of $F$ for a line integral (i.e. the formula) ?

Comment: You parametrize the curve by $\mathbf r(t)$ and integrate $\int_a^b \mathbf F(\mathbf r(t))\cdot \mathbf r'(t)\,dt$.

Comment: Ok so I see now. thanks.